# How to output a variable in a javascript function to text in html

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Im trying to add a random number 1-6 to a variable when you click a Botton. Then, every time you click it adds 1-6 to a variable until you get to 21 or over. I want the total (variable named clicks) to output to an "a" tag in HTML, but the current code does not output the "clicks" variable to the "a" tag in the code.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<h2>Get To 21!</h2>

<div>
<p> Click The Dice To Role! The Counter Below Will Record Your Score!</p>

</div>

<div>

<p id="game"></p>

  </div>

<script>
 var clicks = 0;

  function random()
{
    if (clicks > 21) {
      alert("You Got To 22! You Lose! Please Try Again!");
      location.reload();
    }

    clicks += Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        document.getElementById('clicks').value = rnd;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

};
</script>



<input type="image" value="clicks" onclick="random()" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/black-and-white-dice-png-black-white-dice-bunco-clip-art-dice-images-free-900.jpg" alt="Dice2" width="450" height="280">  

  Total Count: <a id="clicks">0</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Define "isn't working".  What does it do?  How does it fail?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, where specifically does it first fail?

Comment: Look at your browser's debugging tools.  Specifically at the development console.  Observe the error message it's showing you.  (Hint: You're trying to use a variable called `rnd` which you never defined.)

Comment: It seems to me that the random value part of the code works because there is an alert when "clicks" gets over 21. What doesn't work is the part where "clicks" gets outputted to an "a" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable rnd in not defined.

```js
 var clicks = 0;

  function random()
{
    if (clicks > 21) {
      alert("You Got To 22! You Lose! Please Try Again!");
      location.reload();
    }

    clicks += Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
//        document.getElementById('clicks').value = rnd; You have not define this rnd and using this which throws error.
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

};
```

```html
</div>

<div>

<p id="game"></p>

  </div>





<input type="image" value="clicks" onclick="random()" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/black-and-white-dice-png-black-white-dice-bunco-clip-art-dice-images-free-900.jpg" alt="Dice2" width="450" height="280">  

  Total Count: <a id="clicks">0</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A dice has numbers from 1 to 6, so rand should +1!
Define your elements correctly. And cache them.
Create a `gameOver` logic (to check both win or lose)
Don't use inline JS.
Don't reload the page. Reset your `score` instead.

```js
var score = 0;
var el_game = document.getElementById('game');
var el_dice = document.getElementById('dice');

function roll() {
  score +=  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
  game.textContent = score;
  checkGameOver();
};

function checkGameOver() {
  var message = '';
  if (score === 21) {
    message = '21! You won!';
  } else if (score > 21) {
    message = 'Over 22! Try Again!';
  }
  if(message) { // Game is over (we have a message)
    alert(message); // Notify
    score = 0;     // And reset clicks
  }
}

el_dice.addEventListener('click', roll);
```

```html
<button id="dice">ROLL DICE!</button>
<p id="game"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to the image and then use .on('click') to change innerHTML.

```
var clicks = 0;

$('#dice').on('click', function () {
   clicks++;
   $('#clicks').html(clicks);
});
```